# removing elements in an array, c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array of sockets (pfd[nfd].fd). I also have an array of pointers (event_tracking* track[10]). If there comes a point in my code where I try and receive data from a socket that is closed I would like to remove that array element in both arrays and then shift the arrays to fill the empty spot.

```
 for(j=1; j<nfd; j++) {
        if(pfd[j].revents&POLLIN) {  

            char* p = track.receive_datagram();

            if (p == 0) { 
            delete track[j-1];
            //Delete element in pfd[nfd].fd
            //Reorder elements of track array
            //Reorder elements of pfd array
            }

        }
  }
```

I know you can call the delete operator to call the destructor for track but I'm not sure how to reorder the elements in the array now that one is missing? Or how to delete and reorder the pfd array?

Any help would be appreciated! I can't find any examples of deleting and reordering arrays in my text.

Comment: Could you use [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)?

Comment: If the order of the elements is not important, you can just overwrite the deleted item with the last one and decrement the length.

Answer (score 1):

A C++ solution should be to use a `std::vector` or `std::array` and forget about everything (possibly storing smart pointers, eg `std::unique_ptr<T>`).

If you really want to go the hard way you could setup things like these:

- find element to remove (index `i`)
- if `i == LENGTH_OF_ARRAY - 1` do nothing, otherwise swap element at `i` and at `LENGTH_OF_ARRAY - 1` so that the element to be removed is in last position
- call `delete array[LENGTH_OF_ARRAY - 1]` to destroy last element
- call `array = realloc(array, (LENGTH_OF_ARRAY - 1) * sizeof(array[0]))` to release memory in the array for removed element, and update `LENGTH_OF_ARRAY`

Comment: Note that you shouldn't mix `realloc` with `new/new[]` or `delete/delete[]`. You should instead use `malloc` or `calloc` and `free`. You can safely use `new` and `delete` with objects whose pointers are in an array created with `malloc` - that is, you can mix allocators within a given codebase - but you must not mix them on any particular allocation.

Comment: Indeed there is no allocation mixed since `delete` is called on an element of the array but the OP should take care of allocating `array` with `calloc`/`malloc`.

Comment: Right, just wanted to make sure they knew not to use `new` and `delete[]` with an array that they'll want to call `realloc` on. Huh.. now I'm wondering if there's an equivalent of `realloc` for `new`/`delete`...

Comment: There is not an equivalent of `realloc()`, but you can resize a std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your data structures, the solution is to copy each element after the one you remove over the previous element of the array.  This is more efficient for a linked list.  With an array allocated by `new[]`, you would not reallocate anything, but you could resize a `vector`.